# Unable to cast an object at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET MVC 5 (vNext). In an effort to do this, I'm migrating an existing app. In that app, I get a list of classes that implement a specific interface. In an attempt to do this, I am using the following code:

```
// Find all classes that implement IMyInterface
var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var classes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                .Where(y => type.IsAssignableFrom(y) && y.GetInterfaces().Contains(type))
                .ToList();

if (classes == null)
  Console.WriteLine("None found");
else            
  Console.WriteLine(classes.Count + " found."); 

try {
  foreach (var c in classes)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(c.GetType().FullName);
    var converted = (IMyInterface)(c);
    // Never gets here. Exception gets thrown.  
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  // Prints: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
}
```

Unfortunately, an exception is thrown that says: "Cannot cast from source type to destination type.". When I print out the full name of the type, it is `System.MonoType`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: `classes` will never be null, at worst it will be an empty list (having called `.ToList()`)

Comment: If I understand your code correctly then your `classes` would just be a list of `Types`, there isn't any thing gained by casting the `Type` you want an instance of it I presume

Comment: You're trying to cast a _type_ to an `IMyInterface` which  is not possible.  What is your objective?

Comment: @Sayse - I'm trying to get a list of classes that implement `IMyInterface`.

Comment: @ZachTempleton - You've already done that, you don't need to cast it

Comment: @Sayse - I don't understand. If I've already done that, why won't my cast work? How do I get the `IMyInterface`?

Comment: @ZachTempleton - As Jamiec noted in his answer your `classes` is a `List<Type>`, You've already done the filtering in this list to make sure that every one of the types in that list implement your interface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code, `classes` is a `List<Type>`, that is to say these are not instances of your class, they are instances of the class `Type` which describes the class implementing your interface.

Hence this line

```
var converted = (IMyInterface)(c);
```

Will always throw an exception, as `Type` does not implement `IMyInterface`. I suspect what you actually wanted to do is *instantiate* an instance of your class using a `Type` which can be achieved with the static methods on [`Activator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) such as

```
var converted = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(c);
```

---

Expanding on a comment I made on your question

```
if (classes == null)
```

The above line will never evaluate true, you probably wanted to check whether the list is empty

```
if (classes.Count == 0)
```

or, in actual fact you do not need a list here at all, remove the `.ToList()` and consider using

```
// classes now an IEnumerable<Type> - no need for a list here.
var classes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(y => type.IsAssignableFrom(y) && y.GetInterfaces().Contains(type));
if (!classes.Any())
```

Comment: In your last code snippet, you have `.Contains(type)`. What is `type`? is type `var type = typeof(IMyInterface);` or something else altogether?

Comment: I should also mention that I'm trying to find all classes that implement the given interface. That's why I'm using the approach I chose.

Comment: The last snippet was copied directly from your question.